# how to bind dynamic function on HTML element using angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-directive, dynamic-function

I am trying to bind the event on the dynamically created element. I am quite successful but I am not able to bind the function  to the event. here is my code

**.ts code**

```
 data = ['fn1()', 'fn2()', 'fn3()'];
 fn1() { alert(1) }
  fn2() { alert(2) }
  fn3() { alert(3) }
```

**html code**

```
   table>
  <ng-container *ngFor='let d of data'>
    <tr (click)=d>
      <td>
        :) !!!
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
```

but, when I add the function statically then it is getting called, ie.

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor='let d of data'>
    <tr (click)=fn1()>
      <td>
        :) !!!
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>

</table>
```

this works, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an array of functions, not an array of strings. And you want to call the function when the div is clicked:

TypeScript:

```
fn1 = () => { alert(1) };
fn2 = () => { alert(2) };
fn3 = () => { alert(3) };
data = [this.fn1, this.fn2, this.fn3];
```

HTML:

```
<div (click)="d()">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4demmf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: hi, could you just check my editted question, please

Comment: well, it doesnt work when i call like this
 <tr (click)=d>

Comment: Click on the Demo link, and you'll see that it does work. So if it doesn't work with your code, it means your code is not the same as i my answer. Post a complete stackblitz example, as I did.

Comment: could you explain me how this is working, please. thanks for your help

Comment: It creates an array of functions, iterates over it, and creates a div for each of them. When the div is clicked, thanks to `(click)="d()"`, the statement `d()` is executed, and the function stored in the variable `d`, which is one of the functions of the array, is executed.

Comment: how will i pass parameter in this?
fn1 = (data) => { };

Comment: Your functions don't take any parameter. They alert a hard-coded value. Why would you want to pass parameters?

Comment: i have just pasted a simple code so that people would focus on the solution and not get lost on the logic which i have implemented. in the actual logic i would require to pass parameter as well, could you please guide me on how to do that? thanks

Comment: The same way. Declare parameters in your functions (`(foo: string, bar: number) => alert(foo, bar)`, and pass parameter values when calling the function: `d('bla', 1)`.

Comment: but the parameter would be dynamic? then i have to pass it in the array only

Comment: cant we do somtething like this?
data = [this.fn1(1), this.fn2(2), this.fn3(3)];

Comment: You can, but then you won't have an array of functions. you'll have an array containing the results of the calls to fn1, fn2 and fn3. When you have parentheses after a function name, it means that you call the function. What are you trying to achieve, for real?